# Smallest compactification for continuous extension of $\sin(x)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and bounded
and let $K$ be a Hausdorff compactification of $[0, \infty)$ such that $f$ has an extension to a continuous function $F$ on $K$. As an example, if $f(x) = \arctan(x)$ we can take the one-point-compactification $[0, \infty]$ and set $F(\infty) := \frac{\pi}{2}$.

If $f(x) = \sin(x)$ then what is the minimal Hausdorff compactification $K$ of $[0, \infty)$ on which $f$ has a continuous extension? (Is it the Closed Topologist's Sine Curve?) The Stone-Cech compactification is the largest one (up to equivalence).

Comment: You asked your question more than two years ago, so perhaps you are no longer interested in that subject area. But could you define what the "minimal compactification" should be?

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x}: X = [0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,1]$, which is an embedding and $g(x) = \sin(x): [0,\infty) \rightarrow [-1,1]$.

Then $h= (f,g): X \rightarrow [0,1] \times [-1,1]$ is continuous (defined by $h(x) = (f(x),g(x)))$ and as it separates points and closed sets, $h$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ onto $h[X]$ and $g$ can be extended from $\overline{h[X]}$ by the second projection onto $[-1,1]$. So $(\overline{h[X]},h)$ is a compactification that extends the $\sin(x)$ function.

I'd wager this is the minimal way to do it (we need the extra function as $\sin(x)$ is not injective), though I cannot offer a proof for now. The technique is quite generally applicable.

Comment: Doesn't minimality follow from the fact that the extension is injective on the remainder $\overline{h[X]}\setminus h[X]$, because the mapping onto a smaller compactification is a quotient map?

Comment: So, $\overline{h(X)}$ is homeomorphic to the Closed Topologist's Sine Curve.

Comment: @yadaddy I think that's correct.