# The smallest compactification for continuous extension of $\sin(x)$

Tags: general-topology

I would like to ask what the smallest Hausdorff compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ is, onto which we may continuously extend the function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \text{sin}(x)$.

**A weaker / related version of this question** has been asked here, and even that only has a partial answer: [Smallest compactification for continuous extension of $\sin(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843791/smallest-compactification-for-continuous-extension-of-sinx)

There the answer is about *minimal* compactifications; I would like to know about a *smallest* one. I believe, mimicking the answer given there, that the compactification I am looking for is $h=(f,g): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-1,1] \times [-1,1], x \mapsto (\text{tanh}(x),\text{sin}(x)) $.
(The first component is just an embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ into an interval.) Let's call this compactification $(h,\tilde{\mathbb{R}})$. It is my candidate for being a smallest compactification onto which we may extend $g(x)=$ sin$(x)$.

**SUMMARY:** I would like to show that given any compactification $(j, \gamma \mathbb{R})$ such that the function $g(x)=$ sin$(x)$ extends continuously onto it, there exists a continuous map $k$ from $\gamma \mathbb{R}$ to $\tilde{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $kj=h$.

**Idea for proof:** I'm sure it suffices (and is necessary!) to have that $f(x)= $ tanh$(x)$ extends continuously to $(j, \gamma \mathbb{R})$, since by assumption $g(x)$ already extends continuously to it. However the idea I had for constructing an extension of $f(x)$ involves using sequential compactness rather than compactness, which is not allowed because in general the two notions don't coincide. For instance, I've tried to define the extension $\tilde{f}: \gamma \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-1,1]$ as being equal to $f$ on the image of $j$ (obviously!), but then the remaining points of $\gamma \mathbb{R}$ have to go to either $-1$ or $1$ depending on some condition that I've not worked out. I tried to say, let $\tilde{f}$ take the value $1$ (respectively $-1$) on $p \in \gamma \mathbb{R} \backslash j(\mathbb{R})$ if there exists a sequence of distinct real numbers $(x_n)$ such that cos$(x_n)$ tends to $1$ (respectively $-1$) and $j(x_n)$ tends to $p$, but that's not well-defined for every $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the injective map $j\colon\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^3$, $t\mapsto (\sin t,\cos t,  \sin \sqrt 2t)$ and let $\gamma \Bbb R\subset \Bbb R^2$ be the closure of the image of $j$. Clearly, $\gamma \Bbb R$ is the cylinder $S^1\times [-1,1]$. Then $\gamma \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, $(x,y,z)\mapsto x$ is a continuous extension of the sine function, but we cannot map the cylinder suitably to $\tilde{\Bbb R}$ because the points $j(2n\pi)$ and $j(-2n\pi)$ are both dense in $\{(0,1)\}\times [-1,1]$

Comment: Why does the fact that those points are dense prove the cylinder can't map suitably to $\tilde{\mathbb{R}}$?

Comment: Is this argument correct:
If such a suitable mapping $k$ exists, then $k$ has to map that strip ${(0,1)} \times [-1,1]$ to a curve in $\tilde{\mathbb{R}}$ on which the points $kj(2n\pi)=h(2n\pi)$, $kj(-2n\pi)=h(-2n\pi)$ are dense. But no such curve exists... (why)?

Comment: Also, what you wrote shows that my guess of a smallest compactification was incorrect, but we still don't know that a smallest one doesn't exist, right?

Comment: @SSF There is no theorem to tell us that a minimal such compactification exists, no. I believe the set of compactifications of a Tychonoff space $X$ always forms a poset for which sups exist. And $\beta X$ always is maximal. There is a minimal compactification iff $X$ is locally compact. Beyond this not much is known.

Comment: See [these notes](https://www.math.wustl.edu/~freiwald/ch10.pdf) for some more theory. Warning: exercise E2 is wrong...